# Declare constant for 2 dimensional array's size

Tags: objective-c, arrays, constants

I'm beginning Objective-C and I'm trying to create a multidimensionnal array of `integers`, here is how I did it :

**File Constants.h (added in the Prefix.pch file)**

```
typedef enum {
    BOARD_WIDTH=10,
    BOARD_HEIGHT=20
} BoardSizeEnum;
```

**File Board.m**

```
@implementation Board
{
    NSInteger mBoard[BOARD_WIDTH][BOARD_HEIGHT];
}
```

I tried many many way of creating constants for my `width` and `height` and this way is the only one that seems (quite) correct... I also tried with `define` but I don't like this because it's not typed (am I wrong for thinking that ?)...

Is there a better way of creating this ? I feel it's not really clean...

**Edit :**

`NSInteger*` to `NSInteger`, I clearly want an array of `integers`, not pointers.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about #define not being typed, but to each his own. Just as a side note, you're creating a two-dimensional array of integer pointers; you probably just want `NSInteger mBoard[BOARD_WIDTH][BOARD_HEIGHT]` to store the integers in the array directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't declare the sizes like that. Enums are usually used when you have multiple options and you want to give each option a name (instead of just using numbers).

To declare constants for your array, you have a few options.

1. Use **preprocessor macros**:

   `#define BOARD_WIDTH 10`
2. Use **constants**:

   `static const int boardWidth = 10;`

And your declaration is wrong. You're declaring a 2 dimensional array of `NSInteger` **pointers**. It should be like this instead:

```
// assuming width and height is declared as described above.
NSInteger mBoard[width][height];
```

Comment: There you go ! I was looking for your "static const int stuff"... I forgot the static and it wouldn't work... I think that declaring this static const within my const and creating my array this way is definitely what I was looking for, Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *words[26];
    for (i = 0;i<26;) {
    words[i] = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
```

you can use it like this

```
[words[6] addObject:myInt];
[words[6] insertObject:myInt atIndex:4];
[words[6] objectAtIndex:4];
//in this case 6 is the column number and 4 is the row.
```

Comment: What is the benefit of doing this ? Seems excessively painful to init my array, isn't it ?

Comment: OP is using C arrays, not `NSArray`.

Comment: ok, well, this is the method for making a multi-dimensional array and I thought that is what you asked for, but maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: @BobOdenkirk No, in fact, it was more a constants problem than an array creation problem... But since I'm starting with Objective-C, very interesting indeed... Thanks

Comment: Yeah, excuse me sorry maybe my method is overkill if you can do it using a C array like above.... 
This is how I would do it in Objective-C,
Now it seems like maybe your method would be more relevant sorry.